# Word "size" not working as a column name when retrieving data from MS Access

Tags: vba, ms-access, adodb

I have encountered a strange error when trying to retrieve data in VBA from an MS Access database. I get the error:

> Run-time error '-2147467259 (80004005)': Method 'Execute' of object '_Connection' failed.

I initially had a long list of columns in my SQL statement when I got the error but with trial and error I discovered that the issue was with the column named "Size". I since tried to rename the column and it seems like anything works except any versions of the word "size" (Size, size, sizE etc.).

Anyone have an idea of why?

Code:

```
Sub test()
Dim connStr, objConn
Dim sPath As String
sPath = "[path]"
fullPath = sPath & "\[dbname].accdb"

connStr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=" & fullPath
 
'Define object type
Set objConn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
 
'Open Connection
objConn.Open connStr

Dim queryStr As String

queryStr = "SELECT ID, Size FROM primary_table"

Set rs = objConn.Execute(queryStr) 'This is were the error occurs

objConn.Close
Set rs = Nothing
Set objConn = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Not sure if size a reserved word, but try with `[Size]`.

Comment: That worked! Thank you! Is it generally a good idea to always put brackets around the column names?

Comment: When the field name contains space(s), is a keyword or reserved word, you have to put them. In all other cases it's optional, wont make a difference if you put them or not.

Comment: [Access SQL Reserved words](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/sql-reserved-words-b899948b-0e1c-4b56-9622-a03f8f07cfc8) -- you should never use these in table or column names.

Comment: Thank very much to both of you! I have limited experience with MS Access so I was super confused.

Comment: Also, use of punctuation/special characters will mandate use of [ ] - only exception is the underscore character.

Answer (score 1):

As was pointed out in the question comments, "`Size`" is a **reserved word** in Access, so it must be EITHER:

- wrapped in square brackets: `[Size]`; OR
- be "fully qualified" by prefixing it with the table name: `primary_table.Size`

Best practice is to avoid using reserved words as column or table names in the first place.  For a comprehensive list of reserved words, refer to Allen Browne's superb site:

[Problem names and reserved words in Access](http://allenbrowne.com/AppIssueBadWord.html)